# Will continuous poll for pull requests in jenkins put more load on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, polling, pull-request

I'm planning to enable Bitbucket pullrequest builder plugin in Jenkins. For that cron * * * * *(every second) is the preferred way for me.

Will polling every second from multiple Jenkin jobs continuously use more resources on Jenkins server?

Will the Jenkins server get over loaded from multiple jobs polling every second on Bitbucket?

Comment: You're likely to hit a rate limit on bitbucket.org: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/rate-limits-668173227.html

Comment: Is your Jenkins instance reachable by Bitbucket? Both Bitbucket Cloud and Bitbucket Server have webhooks that can trigger something on a particular event